# Delay code behind function

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a css loader and i want to show it for few seconds before calling the log in function in code behind after clicking a button.
Is ther a delay command ?

Comment: Is the login button an asp button control?

Comment: Yes it is, the Thread.Sleep works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, loader should be shown when you actually load something.

If you want to “pause” execution then

```
Thread.Sleep
```

Is an option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep

Comment: I tried it but i didn't know its miliseconds.. thanks